# Text Message Sending Free APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wanted to know that are there any Free APIs available for message sending?
I actually wanted to send a message to minimum 50 people at a time via my application. Is there any Free API available for message sending?

I want to send messages to their cell Numbers.. Is there any API for sending text messages to Cell Numbers?

Comment: SMTP? What kind of messages to you want to send?

Comment: well verification messages i want to send..

Answer (score 14):

You can do that by sending to the email txt address, all cell phones have email addresses you can send to.  Number@provider.

```
* AT&T – cellnumber@txt.att.net
* Verizon – cellnumber@vtext.com
* T-Mobile – cellnumber@tmomail.net
* Sprint PCS - cellnumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
* Virgin Mobile – cellnumber@vmobl.com
* US Cellular – cellnumber@email.uscc.net
* Nextel - cellnumber@messaging.nextel.com
* Boost - cellnumber@myboostmobile.com
* Alltel – cellnumber@message.alltel.com
```

Comment: Abid lives in Pakistan, do you have some Pakistanian operators too?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was thinking just the US... don't know about over there.

Comment: I think this is probably US only (I just tried in the UK and it doesn't work)

Comment: Great..i never new that every cell no has an email id associated..

Comment: It isn't US only.  Many international carriers have SMS gateways as well.  See the three links at the bottom this page for details:  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/

Answer (score 1):

2 possible solutions are:

- Include the addresses that you want to hide as BCc in the email
- Create an email group on your mail server (containing all the individual email addresses) and use that email group address in your C# code

or do like this ...

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

then further down your code...

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.CC.Add("allemailgroup@yourdomain.com");

foreach (string recipient in recipients) // assuming recipients is a List<string>
{
    message.Bcc.Add(recipient);
}
```

**EDIT:**  there are three ways to send text messages to cell

- Using a GSM modem: Better when one wants to implement offline
  applications and a very small number of SMS go every minute, usually
  few 10s.
- Using web service: Better when it is an online application and a very
  few number of SMS go every minute, usually few 10s.
- Using endpoints given by service the provider: Better when the number
  of SMS exceeds a few 100s per minute. Service provider demands a
  commitment

I strongly recommend you pls go through this link [for more information](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Sending_SMS_using_Net.aspx)

of at least 100,000 SMS per month.

Comment: helpfull! :) but still confused..

Comment: can i be sending free sms? :/